# How to access Redux store data from a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-functional-component

Currently I am working on a new page(functional component) that needs access to data from another page(class component).The data is store in the Redux store since I can display it with store.getState() in the class component. How would I access that data from the functional component?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You would use the connect function: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect

Comment: why you dont try to access the state by using redux store in the functional component?

Comment: `const something = useSelector(state => state.reducer)`

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.

1. You use the [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples) hook
2. You can wrap your component by the [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form) method
3. You can pass store by props from parent to children and call getState method